# Cross Domain API authentication

Tags: php, api, laravel, cross-domain, lumen

I need to expose a JSON webservice to another branch of the company, they will manage their own users table in a public web app while my app is only accesible when a different set of users are inside our office's LAN. The plan so far is that they will consume the webservice using AJAX requests and I should return JSON but I don't know how to authenticate without exposing the credentials in the HTML source code. The basic workflow would be:

1. User X logs in other branch's web app (I don't have control over this process)
2. User X clicks a button and other branch's server makes a request to my server
3. My server fetches the data and returns JSON
4. other server populates a dropdow (or something like that)

I've read a few tutorials about APIs but all of them talk about adding a token field in the users table and that won't be my case. What would be a secure way to do it? Even when it´s inside our corporate LAN I wouldn't want to expose the web services without authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the other branch's web app is a client of your web app.  The most standardized and accepted way to approach authorizing *their* web app to make requests to *your* web app is to integrate the two applications via [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

With an OAuth server, web applications that wish to integrate with your service are dubbed 'clients'.  Each client is issued both a `client_id` and a `client_secret`.  There's a few different flows you can follow, each with their own preconditions and expectations. I won't rehash them here, but [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) looks like it has a pretty good summary and can serve you well as a getting started guide.

I will say that I think the easiest flow to implement is the Password Grant, but requires that you completely trust the integrating application, since it will know your users' login credentials.  From your description of the problem, it doesn't seem like this would be an issue.

<sub>Note- the linked DigitalOcean article refers to Password Grant flow as "Password Credentials Flow"</sub>

Once integrated, an authorization token is requested and kept within the client application. How it is requested and retrieved depends on which grant flow you are following.  Each request to your API includes this 'bearer' token inside of an `Authorization` header, which is then checked and validated on your resource server. Only requests containing valid tokens will actually be served with data from *your* application.

I have used [lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package to implement an OAuth2 server in Laravel without too much of a headache, but it looks like since Laravel 5.3 it has been deprecated. You can look into trying [laravel/passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport), which I have no experience with.